# Cast Object to Generic Type for returning

Tags: java, generics, casting

Is there a way to cast an object to return value of a method?
I tried this way but it gave a compile time exception in "instanceof" part:

```
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof T) {
        return (T) o;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also tried this one but it gave a runtime exception, ClassCastException:

```
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(Object o) {
    try {
        T rv = (T)o;
        return rv;
    } catch(java.lang.ClassCastException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there a possible way of doing this easily:

```
String s = convertInstanceOfObject("string");
System.out.println(s); // should print "string"
Integer i = convertInstanceOfObject(4);
System.out.println(i); // should print "4"
String k = convertInstanceOfObject(345435.34);
System.out.println(k); // should print "null"
```

EDIT: I wrote a working copy of the correct answer:

```
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(Object o, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return clazz.cast(o);
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = convertInstanceOfObject("string", String.class);
    System.out.println(s);
    Integer i = convertInstanceOfObject(4, Integer.class);
    System.out.println(i);
    String k = convertInstanceOfObject(345435.34, String.class);
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

Comment: why the last one should print `null`? and, why don't you return an `Object`? Java erasure will anyway translate your generic into an `Object`, so why don't you write directly `public static Object convertInstanceOfObject`?

Comment: I can decide the later one later, but I wanted to catch ClassCastException :) The thing I wanted to know is that an object is an instance of another object before casting, where I don't know its actual type.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You have to use a `Class` instance because of the generic type erasure during compilation.

```
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(Object o, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return clazz.cast(o);
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The declaration of [that method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) is:

```
public T cast(Object o)
```

This can also be used for array types. It would look like this:

```
final Class<int[]> intArrayType = int[].class;
final Object someObject = new int[]{1,2,3};
final int[] instance = convertInstanceOfObject(someObject, intArrayType);
```

Note that when `someObject` is passed to `convertToInstanceOfObject` it has the compile time type `Object`.

Comment: I know it's from the OP, but really `{ catch(ClassCastException e) {   return null;    }` is unforgiveable

Comment: @SpaceTrucker, thanks. I'm wondering, would be any way to use .isArray() inside convertInstanceOfObject() in the someObject and extract the class (as the intArrayType) from it by reflection and then call an internal private method passing those?
But even doing this, I must to create an empty array and pass it in the public method, right?

Comment: It should be mentioned that type erasure actually happens at compilation, not runtime.

Answer (score 28):

I stumble upon this question and it grabbed my interest. The accepted answer is completely correct, but I thought I do provide my findings at JVM byte code level to explain why the OP encounter the `ClassCastException`.

I have the code which is pretty much the same as OP's code:

```
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(Object o) {
    try {
       return (T) o;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String k = convertInstanceOfObject(345435.34);
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

and the corresponding byte code is:

```
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: areturn
       2: astore_1
       3: aconst_null
       4: areturn
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
           0     1     2   Class java/lang/ClassCastException

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #3                  // double 345435.34d
       3: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
       6: invokestatic  #6                  // Method convertInstanceOfObject:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
       9: checkcast     #7                  // class java/lang/String
      12: astore_1
      13: getstatic     #8                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      16: aload_1
      17: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      20: return
```

Notice that `checkcast` byte code instruction happens in the main method not the `convertInstanceOfObject` and `convertInstanceOfObject` method does not have any instruction that can throw `ClassCastException`. Because the main method does not catch the `ClassCastException` hence when you execute the main method you will get a `ClassCastException` and not the expectation of printing `null`.

Now I modify the code to the accepted answer:

```
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(Object o, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return clazz.cast(o);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String k = convertInstanceOfObject(345435.34, String.class);
        System.out.println(k);
    }
```

The corresponding byte code is:

```
public static <T> T convertInstanceOfObject(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class<T>);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: aload_0
       2: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/lang/Class.cast:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
       5: areturn
       6: astore_2
       7: aconst_null
       8: areturn
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
           0     5     6   Class java/lang/ClassCastException

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #4                  // double 345435.34d
       3: invokestatic  #6                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
       6: ldc           #7                  // class java/lang/String
       8: invokestatic  #8                  // Method convertInstanceOfObject:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      11: checkcast     #7                  // class java/lang/String
      14: astore_1
      15: getstatic     #9                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      18: aload_1
      19: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      22: return
```

Notice that there is an `invokevirtual` instruction in the `convertInstanceOfObject` method that calls `Class.cast()` method which throws `ClassCastException` which will be catch by the `catch(ClassCastException e)` bock and return `null`; hence, "null" is printed to console without any exception.

Answer (score 25):

If you do not want to depend on throwing exception (which you probably should not) you can try this:

```
public static <T> T cast(Object o, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.isInstance(o) ? clazz.cast(o) : null;
}
```

Comment: Much better. I hate exception-based program flows.

In my case, I wanted to check whether the object in question implements an interface. For that, I used `isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: Why not add a type bound to the generic argument instead? `public static <T extends Foo> T cast(....)` instead of checking whether it is a `Foo`

Comment: Aren't exception based flows better than passing nulls around? @intra