# Copy Database table data to text file without looping recordset

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Is it possible to get the result set data to single string (for writing to notepad)? Using record set we need to loop through each fields.

Is there any other way we can get to a single string without loop through each fields? I am able to do this in VBA by copying the entire recordset to an excel sheet.

Comment: _for writing to notepad..._ Why? Sounds like a xy-problem

Comment: There is no 'recordset' in standard Java. Please be precise in what you mean. Did you mean `java.sql.ResultSet` instead?

Comment: Mainly it depends on how do you get a data from a DB. If it's a core java - there is a one way, if a Spring or another framework app - another case

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes java.sql.ResultSet

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov Its core java

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really something in standard Java that does this for you, except maybe using [`javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/WebRowSet.html) and one of its `writeXml` methods, but that is a very specific and verbose format.

If you want to output a result set in a specific format, you will need to do this yourself, or find a library that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general you have to convert a result set into an any DTO class whatever you want and then implement a `toString()` method in the way you want to be.
There are some ways to achive this. Here is a one:
[Mapping a JDBC ResultSet to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956042/mapping-a-jdbc-resultset-to-an-object)