# How to write a method that accepts a class type as a parameter, and uses it to cast some objects

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8

I am working on a **Java 8** desktop application using **JavaFX 8**.
I have this method in the MainApp class *(the one that extends the Application class)*.

```
public void showUserLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/userLayout.fxml"));
        AnchorPane userPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        rootAnchorPane.getChildren().clear();
        rootAnchorPane.getChildren().add(userPane);

        userLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

and I am using the same code for each layout I want to load.

Is there any way to create a method that accepts the class type as a parameter and does the exact same job, for example:

```
public void genericLayoutLoader(String fxmlFilename, Class rootFXMLElement, Class fxmlController) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(fxmlFilename));
        // Not sure for the Object below
        Object chooseUserAndInterval = (rootFXMLElement) loader.load();
        // rootAnchorPane is same for every layout
        rootAnchorPane.getChildren().clear();
        rootAnchorPane.getChildren().add((rootFXMLElement) chooseUserAndInterval);

        Object controller = (fxmlController) loader.getController();
        ((fxmlController)controller).setMainApp(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

I would use it like this:

```
public void showUserLayout() {
    genericLayoutLoader("view/userLayout.fxml", AnchorPane, userLayoutController);  
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Can't you solve it by letting all of them implement some common interface?

Comment: Do you mean something like [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524751/cast-object-to-generic-type-for-returning/14524815#14524815)?

Comment: @KDM The `showSomeLayout` methods are defined all in the MainApp class. So, with that in mind, I don't think this can be done, right?

Comment: @Chris not sure without seeing more code. I am also handicapped because I don't know much of JavaFx. See my answer below. Might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to using Classes as parameters, your code should look somewhat like this:

```
    public void genericLayoutLoader(String fxmlFilename, Class rootFXMLElement, Class fxmlController) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(fxmlFilename));
            // Not sure for the Object below
            Object chooseUserAndInterval = loader.load();
            // rootAnchorPane is same for every layout
            rootAnchorPane.getChildren().clear();
            rootAnchorPane.getChildren().add(chooseUserAndInterval);

            Object controller = loader.getController();
            fxmlController.getMethod("setMainApp", new Class[] { MainApp.class }).invoke(controller, this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showUserLayout() {
        genericLayoutLoader("view/userLayout.fxml", AnchorPane.class, Controller.class);  
    }
```

But, I still suggest to try to solve this using interfaces if possible.

Comment: I was trying this as I've posted the question, but could not get past calling the setMainApp method. I've tried your way, and I got `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.nomad.view.userLayoutController.setMainApp()`. Could you point me as to how would I do this using interfaces?

Comment: What is the signature for `setMainApp`?

Comment: It's `public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp)` - thank you for your time!

Comment: Updated the `getMethod` call. See whether it helps.

Comment: It works just fine now, thank you!   
But could you point me to an example with your recommendation on using interfaces? If that's a good practice, I'd like use it.

Comment: @jovit.royeca answer is more like it. But without seeing more code - won't be able to provide better answer.

Comment: `Class.getMethod` is a varargs method. So there is no need for a `new Class[]`…

Comment: @Holger true. When I posted code first, I don't know the type, left it as place holder. Invoke I used varargs version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface as a parameter in the method. Then pass in implementations of the interface as a parameter when you call the method.

```
interface Loader {
    void load();
}

interface Controller {
    void setMainApp(Object mainApp);
}
```

Here is a class that implements the loader interface:

```
class AnchorPane implements Loader {
    void load() {
        System.out.println("Loading...");
    }
}
```

And here is a class that implements the Controller interface:

```
class UserLayoutController implements Controller {
    void setMainApp(Object mainApp) {
        System.out.println("Setting main app...");
    }
}
```

Change the method definition to this:

```
public void genericLayoutLoader(String fxmlFilename, Loader loader, Controller controller) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(fxmlFilename));

        // rootAnchorPane is same for every layout
        rootAnchorPane.getChildren().clear();
        rootAnchorPane.getChildren().add(loader);

        controller.setMainApp(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

Then call it somewhere in your code:

```
genericLayoutLoader("view/userLayout.fxml", new AnchorPane(), new UserLayoutController());
```

Comment: 1. In JavaFX, the AnchorPane class is provided, and I am not extending it, instead just using it as a member. So the `loader interface` would be implemented in each controller? In that case, that means a new load method, for each controller. I want to avoid creating methods that do the same thing, only with different objects.  
2. I think that this line `rootAnchorPane.getChildren().add(loader);` isn't equivalent to passing the actual AnchorPane object, after I've loaded it from the FXML Loader. I might be missing sth with this notation though, as I am not that experienced with Java yet.

Comment: [2-continue] Also, the loader interface, has a method that returns nothing, so how would that `.add(loader)` work?

Answer (score 0):

1) For the Type of object which you are not sure, consider using a wildcard.

Refer to this: [When to use generic methods and when to use wild-card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card)

2) Once you get the object, now you can use the instance Of operator to check the type of object and perform steps specific to this object like:-

```
if(object instanceof AnchorPane){
//do this
} else if(object instance of  BorderPane){
//do this
}
```