# Casting versus function parameterisation

Tags: java, parameters, casting, abstraction

I have a class with generic functions, which I would like to reuse for different Object types to avoid redundant code.

From what I can see, there are two ways to go in this case, which is to either:

1. Return `Object` in the generic function an cast the result each time I use it
2. Parameterise the function and specify the Object Type when I call it (which will trigger an unchecked cast warning).

My questions are therefore:

1. What is are the differences I need to consider when selecting either strategy?
2. Why do I get a "Unchecked cast" warning with the parametrisation approach if the information Java has at runtime at each point is pretty much identical?

**Casting:**

```java
public class Car {
  public Car createNew(String symKey) {
    Svc svc = new Svc();
    Car car = (Car) svc.getBySymKey(symKey);
  }
}
public class Svc { 

  public Object getBySymKey(String symKey) {
    return DB.getBySymKey(symKey);
  }
}
```

**Parameterisation:**

```java
public interface ObjSvcIntf {
  <E> E getBySymKey(String symKey);
}   

public abstract class ObjSvcImpl implements ObjSvcIntf {

  public Class<?> servicedClass;

  // CONSTRUCTOR
  public ObjSvcImpl (Class<?> servicedClass) {
    this.servicedClass = servicedClass;
  }

  public <E> E getBySymKey(String symKey){
    return (E) DB.getBySymKey(this.servicedClass, symKey);
  }

}

public class DriverSvc { 

  public Class<?> servicedClass;

  public DriverSvc () {
    this.servicedClass = Driver.class;
  }
}



public class CarSvc { 

  public Class<?> servicedClass;

  public CarSvc () {
    this.servicedClass = Car.class;
  }

  public Driver getDriver(String symKey) {
    return new DriverSvc().<Driver>getBySymKey(symKey);
  }

}

public class DB {
  public static <E> E getBySymKey (Class<?> entityClass, String symKey)
    Query query = DB.s.createQuery("from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " where     symKey = : symKey);
    query.setParameter("symKey", symKey);
    return (E) query.getResultList().get(0);
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Is a new parameter `targetType` with the expression [`targetType.cast(tmpObject)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931063/java-method-with-generic-return-type) inevitable in the second case?

Comment: May I ask why not?

Comment: What is `DB`? Does its `getBySymKey` method return `Object`? To make it really type-safe (so that you do not need casting at all) you would need to make `DB.getBySymKey(...)` generic as well, so that it returns the appropriate type.

Comment: I misread your code sorry. Usually, generic parameters are only composed of one letter so we don't mix them up with class names

Comment: I don't think you need to do `Car car = svc.<Car>getBySymKey(symKey)`, `Car car = svc.getBySymKey(symKey)` should work since it infers the type

Comment: not in the casting example, thats correct. I've adjusted that accordingly. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Jesper I added some more context to show the setup. I know the getDriver method could be part of the model, its an unfortunate illustration but I hope the idea comes accross. Its about getting objects that are not immediately connected via the object model.
EDIT: return (E) query.getResultList().get(0); in DB.getSymKey() also throws  a cast warning of course.

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to avoid casting altogether, but it's best to have as little casting as possible (casting means you are deliberately telling the compiler to skip type checking). So it's better to have one cast in class `DB` (with a warning) than let it return `Object` and cast everywhere where you are calling the method.