# Ambiguous behaviour in casting

Tags: java, generics, casting

I was teaching students the old-school Generics and came across an unseen! behavior while I was presenting! :(

I have a simple class

```
public class ObjectUtility {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(castToType(10,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()));
  }

  private static <V,T> T castToType(V value, T type){
    return (T) value;
  }

}
```

This gives output as 10,without any error!!! I was expecting this to give me a ClassCastException, with some error like Integer cannot be cast to HashMap.

Curious and Furious, I tried `getClass()` on the return value, something like below

```
System.out.println(castToType(10,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()).getClass());
```

which is throwing a ClassCastException as I expected.

Also, when I break the same statement into two, something like

```
Object o = castToType(10,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>());
System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

It is not throwing any error and prints `class java.lang.Integer`

All are executed with

```
openjdk version "1.7.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 7.23.0.1-macosx) (build 1.7.0_181-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 7.23.0.1-macosx) (build 24.181-b01, mixed mode)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on Why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: As @Michael said in his answer. To understand better what's happening, have a look at [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)

Comment: Sure @kenny_k, but still I am unclear on the second part of answer I am expecting

Comment: Enabling all compiler warnings would have shed some light on this.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524751/cast-object-to-generic-type-for-returning/14524815

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`T` doesn't exist at runtime. It resolves to the lower bound of the constraint. In this case, there are none, so it resolves to `Object`. Everything can be cast to `Object`, so no class cast exception.

If you were to do change the constraint to this

```
private static <V,T extends Map<?,?>> T castToType(V value, T type){
    return (T) value;
}
```

then the cast to `T` becomes a cast to the lower bound `Map`, which obviously `Integer` is not, and you get the class cast exception you're expecting.

---

> Also, when I break the same statement into two, something like
>
> ```
> Object o = castToType(10,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>());
> System.out.println(o.getClass());
> ```
>
> It is not throwing any error

```
castToType(10,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()).getClass()
```

This throws a class cast exception because it statically links to the method `HashMap::getClass` (**not** `Object::getClass`) since the signature says to expect `HashMap` as a return value. This necessitates an implicit cast to `HashMap` which fails because `castToType` returns an `Integer` at runtime.

When you use this first

```
Object o = castToType(10,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>());
```

you are now statically linking against `Object::getClass` which is fine regardless of what's actually returned.

The "unsplit" version is equivalent to this

```
final HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = castToType(10, new HashMap<>());
System.out.println(map.getClass());
```

which hopefully demonstrates the difference

Comment: Cool, Yeah. Sounds right for the first scenario. Can you also explain why `System.out.println(castToType(10,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()).getClass());` was throwing exception whereas if I break the same into two different statements, I am not getting any?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That surely is a puzzle for beginners and even professionals sometimes!! Appreciate your effort in putting this with nice and simple words!!

Comment: @MohamedAneesA Sure, no problem. I suspect my explanation would have been much worse with however many pairs of students' eyes staring at me expectantly ;)

Comment: Yeah! somehow I hid my face under the podium sometime! I'll explain them tomorrow and remember to quote this answer! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You could see the differences using javap tool.

The compiling process by default makes code optimizations that changes the Generic types  into the primitive ones

First code:

```
public class ObjectUtility {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(castToType(10,new java.util.HashMap<Integer,Integer>()));
  }

  private static <V,T> T castToType(V value, T type){
    return (T) value;
  }

}
```

Real PseudoCode:

```
Compiled from "ObjectUtility.java"
public class ObjectUtility {
  public ObjectUtility();
    descriptor: ()V
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 1: 0

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: bipush        10
       5: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       8: new           #4                  // class java/util/HashMap
      11: dup
      12: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/util/HashMap."<init>":()V
      15: invokestatic  #6                  // Method castToType:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      18: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      21: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 4: 0
      line 5: 21

  private static <V, T> T castToType(V, T);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: areturn
    LineNumberTable:
      line 8: 0
}
```

The calls of the Generic types are changed to Object and an Integer.valueOf is added on the System out print.

Second code:

```
public class ObjectUtility {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(castToType(10,new java.util.HashMap<Integer,Integer>()).getClass());
  }

  private static <V,T> T castToType(V value, T type){
    return (T) value;
  }

}
```

Real Pseudo Code:

```
Compiled from "ObjectUtility.java"
public class ObjectUtility {
  public ObjectUtility();
    descriptor: ()V
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 1: 0

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: bipush        10
       5: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       8: new           #4                  // class java/util/HashMap
      11: dup
      12: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/util/HashMap."<init>":()V
      15: invokestatic  #6                  // Method castToType:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      18: checkcast     #4                  // class java/util/HashMap
      21: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
      24: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      27: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 4: 0
      line 5: 27

  private static <V, T> T castToType(V, T);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: areturn
    LineNumberTable:
      line 8: 0
}
```

The checkcast is invoqued over HashMap but the signature is changed to Object and the returnt is the value as int without the cast inside castToType. The "int" primitive type causes an invalid cast

Third Code:

```
public class ObjectUtility {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = castToType(10,new java.util.HashMap<Integer,Integer>());
    System.out.println(o.getClass());
  }

  private static <V,T> T castToType(V value, T type){
    return (T) value;
  }

}
```

Real Pseudo Code:

```
Compiled from "ObjectUtility.java"
public class ObjectUtility {
  public ObjectUtility();
    descriptor: ()V
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 1: 0

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    Code:
       0: bipush        10
       2: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: new           #3                  // class java/util/HashMap
       8: dup
       9: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/util/HashMap."<init>":()V
      12: invokestatic  #5                  // Method castToType:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      15: astore_1
      16: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      19: aload_1
      20: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
      23: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      26: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 4: 0
      line 5: 16
      line 6: 26

  private static <V, T> T castToType(V, T);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: areturn
    LineNumberTable:
      line 9: 0
}
```

At this case the method is similar to the first one. castToType returns the first parameter without change.

As you can see the java compiler mades some "performance" changes that could affect in some cases. The Generics are an "invention" of the source code that are finally converted to the real type required in any case.

Comment: But good effort anyway. I couldn't be bothered to check the bytecode

Comment: @Dubas Thanks for the effort! I guess both answers are equally right... I must learn more about how to interpret  `javap` output

Comment: @MohamedAneesA [Cheatsheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

Comment: @Michael Thanks!! Would go through!

Comment: @Michael.  The Pseudo Code is any kind of interpreation of a real code or the byte code, Using the "javap" tool it generates a "Pseudo Code" that is near to the bytecode in the class but more "human readable". But also a natural language used to interpret a future coding could be called "Pseudo Code", is not a real source code but allows to describe the process.