# Return type of Object instead of expected type E

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm having an issue regarding the return type of line 20 in method being of type Object, rather than what I would expect the type to be, which is generic E. I'm working on a larger scale program currently but have condensed the issue I'm having into the short code snippet below. Why is the arr[0].getData() in 'method' returning an Object? Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
public class Testing<E> {

    foo[] arr;

    class foo<T> {
        public T data;
        public foo(T in) {
            data = in;
        }
        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public Testing() {
        arr = new foo[5];
    }

    public E method() {
        return arr[0].getData();
        // Required type E, provided type: Object
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast Object to Generic Type for returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524751/cast-object-to-generic-type-for-returning)

Comment: Check your compiler output. You should be getting warnings about raw types each time you write `foo` and not `foo<E>`.

Comment: "I'm having an issue regarding the return type of line 20 in method being of type Object, rather than what I would expect the type to be, which is generic E" Talk me through your logic. Why do you expect the E type? When you write `arr = new foo[5];`, what do you expect to be the template type used? Why? What type do you expect to be instantiated for the `.data` of each of those elements? Why? Also, aside from satisfying the compiler, you understand that *none of this actually creates any Foo instances*, right? So you will just get a `NullPointerException` at runtime anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is because you did not specify the type argument `E` when you created the variable `foo`. Instead of

```
foo[] arr;
```

the variable declaration should be

```
foo<E>[] arr;
```

Comment: you should have started your answer with "a generic array is a terrible idea..."

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
public class Testing<E> {

    foo[] arr;

    class foo<T> {
        public T data;
        public foo(T in) {
            data = in;
        }
        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public Testing() {
        
        arr = new foo<E>[5] ;
    }

    public E method() {
        return arr[0].getData();
        // Required type E, provided type: Object
    }
}
```